# How To Run a Flask App on EC2 Public IP Instead of Private IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a Flask app I want to run on an AWS EC2 instance.

When I do flask run --host=0.0.0.0, the output says its running on all addresses (0.0.0.0), localhost (127.0.0.1), and my AWS EC2's private IPv4 address. I need it to run on the public one so it's accessible anywhere on the internet. When I use the public address for the host argument, it says "Cannot assign requested address".

Comment: What are the current network settings associated with your EC2 instance?

Comment: If it's bound to the private IPv4 address, then you should be able to access it via the 1:1 NAT of EC2, no program running on the EC2 instance itself can directly bind to the Elastic IP.

Comment: Did you have a specific network setting in mind? I have the proper inbound rules set for the instance's security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use the public address for the host argument, it says "Cannot assign requested address".

If your ENI (Elastic Network Interface) has an Elastic IP attached (or a dynamic Publiс IP), all packets are NAT'd between your public and private IPs. It happens outside the EC2 instance.

The EC2 instance only sees the private IPs of the ENI's attached to it.

> I need it to run on the public one so it's accessible anywhere on the internet.

1. Set up an inbound rule on a [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/security-group-rules.html#security-group-rule-characteristics) attached to the interface, which would allow traffic to your destination port
2. Listen on the private address of your ENI, or on 0.0.0.0

This way, requests made to your public IP will reach your Flask app, even if it only listens on the private IP.

Comment: What options should I chooser for the rule?

Comment: @yourambam: port range: whatever your Flask instance listens on. source: whatever addresses/network blocks on the Internet you want to be able to connect (0.0.0.0/0 if everyone)

Comment: I already have a rule with 5000 for the port (the default Flask value) and "My IP address" for the source field.

Comment: @yourambam: then your problem lies elsewhere. Can you SSH to your EC2 instance? What exactly happens when you're trying to issue HTTP requests to your Flask app?

Comment: I can ssh into it fine. When I enter the ip plus the port into my browser, it just loads forever.

Comment: I tried it on a minimal hello world flask app too, so I know its not a problem with my code.

Comment: @yourambam: if you can SSH, then you have a working public IP address and a working security group rule for port 22. Copy it, changing just the port, see if it works. Try running requests with curl/postman. You might have some firewall/iptables issues on the EC2 instance, or on your client machine, or something like that. Install tshark and try capturing the packets. Again, what I wrote in my post is just how it's done on EC2.

Comment: I changed it from 5000 to 5001, and now it works. I don't know why this fixed it, but I'm just glad it works now. 